# Color both column and cell

Tags: excel, vba

can you help me? how to colored automatically the cell and column base on where we put  selected cell? for example when we selected cell D4 and Row D will be colored until column 4 and Column 4 also will be colored just until Row D

thankyou, 
andre

Answer (score 0):

**Introduction**

The -2 and the Close(1) (as I write) will be because questions which sound like "Solve my entire problem for me" are not popular here.  This site is for programmers to help other programmers develop so they can solve their own problems.

However, I was not sure if what you seek was possible and I was interested so I have coded what I believe is a complete solution.  I think I have thought of everything and, with one exception, it all appears to work as I would wish.  The exception is with the workbook save.  If the highlighting is removed prior to the save (so that there is no highlighting in the saved workbook), the user is asked if the workbook is to be saved even if they have already requested a save because removing the highlighting is a change.  You will always be asked if the workbook is to be saved, because of the highlighting, even if there has been no other change.

This code relies on events and event routines.  When an event occurs, Excel looks for an user-coded event routine.  If it exists, Excel executes that routine.  Such routines can do anything that a normal macro can do.

This code will have to be installed in every workbook for which you require this functionality.  I do not think you can install it in the PERSONAL workbook and make it available to all workbooks but I have not tried.

**Installation**

Open the workbook for which you require this functionally and open the VB Editor.

You need a module containing:

```
' Used by cell highlighting code
Public CellHighColLast As Long
Public CellHighRowLast As Long
```

This can be any module including one created specially to hold these variables

In the Project Explorer, you will have a line for "Microsoft Excel Objects".  If there is a "+" to the left of "Microsoft Excel Objects", click it and it will change to a "-".

Under "Microsoft Excel Objects" there is a line for every worksheet plus, at the bottom, "ThisWorkbook".

If you click the line for the top sheet, a blank code area reserved for that worksheet will be displayed.  Paste the code below into that code area:

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal TargetCrnt As Range)

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long

  ColCrnt = TargetCrnt.Column
  RowCrnt = TargetCrnt.Row

  Debug.Print "User has moved cursor within worksheet " & _
              TargetCrnt.Worksheet.Name & " from " & _
              Replace(Cells(CellHighRowLast, CellHighColLast).Address, "$", "") & _
              " to " & _
              Replace(Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt).Address, "$", "")

  ' Remove highlighting from previous active cell
  With Range(Cells(CellHighRowLast, 1), Cells(CellHighRowLast, CellHighColLast))
    .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
  End With
  With Range(Cells(1, CellHighColLast), Cells(CellHighRowLast, CellHighColLast))
    .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
  End With

  ' Hightlight new cell
  With Range(Cells(RowCrnt, 1), Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt))
    .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)        ' Pale yellow
  End With
  With Range(Cells(1, ColCrnt), Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt))
   .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)        ' Pale yellow
  End With

  ' Record new active cell as last cell ready for next move
  CellHighColLast = ColCrnt
  CellHighRowLast = RowCrnt

End Sub
```

You need to click the line for every sheet and paste the above code into its code area.

Finally click the "ThisWorkbook" line and paste the following code into its code area:

```
Option Explicit
Sub Workbook_Open()

  ' The workbook has just been opened:

  ' Record initial active cell as last cell ready for next move
  CellHighColLast = ActiveCell.Column
  CellHighRowLast = ActiveCell.Row

  Debug.Print "Workbook opened with active cell being " & ActiveSheet.Name & _
              "!" & Replace(ActiveCell.Address, "$", "")

  ' Highlight active cell
  With Range(Cells(CellHighRowLast, 1), Cells(CellHighRowLast, CellHighColLast))
   .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)        ' Pale yellow
  End With
  With Range(Cells(1, CellHighColLast), Cells(CellHighRowLast, CellHighColLast))
   .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)        ' Pale yellow
  End With

End Sub
'Private Sub Workbook_BeforeSave(ByVal SaveAsUi As Boolean, Cancel As Boolean)
'
'  Debug.Print "User is saving workbook"
'
'  ' Remove highlighting from active cell before saving
'  With Range(Cells(CellHighRowLast, 1), Cells(CellHighRowLast, CellHighColLast))
'    .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
'  End With
'  With Range(Cells(1, CellHighColLast), Cells(CellHighRowLast, CellHighColLast))
'    .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
'  End With
'
'End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetActivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

  ' The user has selected a new worksheet or has created a new worksheet.

  Debug.Print "User has selected worksheet" & Sh.Name

  Dim ColCrnt As Long
  Dim RowCrnt As Long

  ColCrnt = ActiveCell.Column
  RowCrnt = ActiveCell.Row

  ' Hightlight active cell
  With Range(Cells(RowCrnt, 1), Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt))
   .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)        ' Pale yellow
  End With
  With Range(Cells(1, ColCrnt), Cells(RowCrnt, ColCrnt))
   .Interior.Color = RGB(255, 255, 153)        ' Pale yellow
  End With

  ' Record new active cell as last cell ready for next move
  CellHighColLast = ColCrnt
  CellHighRowLast = RowCrnt

End Sub
Private Sub Workbook_SheetDeactivate(ByVal Sh As Object)

  ' The user has selected a new worksheet or has created a new worksheet.

  Debug.Print "User has left worksheet" & Sh.Name

  ' Remove highlighting from old worksheet
  With Sh
    With .Range(.Cells(CellHighRowLast, 1), _
                .Cells(CellHighRowLast, CellHighColLast))
      .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
    With .Range(.Cells(1, CellHighColLast), _
                .Cells(CellHighRowLast, CellHighColLast))
      .Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
    End With
  End With

End Sub
```

Save the workbook and exit.  If you get any macro errors, click <kbd>End</kbd>; the error will have been caused because the functionality is initialised when the workbook is opened.

**How this works**

Within the "ThisWorkbook" code area there is an event routine called `Workbook_Open()`.  As the name suggests, this is called when the workbook is opened and before the user is given control.  This routine saves the initial position of the cursor and highlights the active cell.  I have used pale yellow but you can change to any colour you prefer.  Note I have included Debug.Print statements to record cursor movements and worksheet changes in the Immediate Window.  I suggest you delete these after an initial test of these macros.

When the user moves the cursor within a worksheet, the `Worksheet_SelectionChange()` event routine in the worksheet's code area is executed.  This routine removes the highlighting from the old active cell and applies it to the new active cell.

When the user switches worksheets, the `Workbook_SheetDeactivate()` and `Workbook_SheetActivate` event routines in "ThisWorkbook" are executed.  The first removes the highlighting from the old worksheet while the second adds it to the new worksheet.

I have included the `Workbook_BeforeSave()` routine I coded but have commented it out.  This routine removes highlighting before the save but causes a repeat of the "do you want to save"  question.  You may wish to uncomment out this routine and experiment with it.